# spring boot thymeleaf generic entity edit page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot 2.1.2 ...

I wonder if there is an existing concept or feature in spring boot to create a generic add or edit page for common entities with a CrudRepository?
I want to omit writing all the boilerplate code again and again for adding or editing pages in thymeleaf and use a generic page instead.

So what I would like to do instead is a generic form like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/edit-$entityName}" th:object="${entity}" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" id="id"/>

<!-- iterating over each field and creating an input form element -->
        <div class="form-group" th:each="field: ${fields}">
            <label for="${field}" th:text="${field}"/>
            <input type="text" th:value="${entity['name']}" th:attr="id=#{${field}}, placeholder=#{$field}" class="form-control">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors($field)}" th:errors="*{$field}"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">save</button>
    </form>
```

With a Controller which is adding the fields:

```
@Controller
public class EntityController {

  @Autowired
  private EntityService service;

  @RequestMapping("/edit-entity/{id}")
  public String editProject(Map<String, Object> model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Optional<MyEntity> byId = service.getById(id);
    model.put("entity", byId.orElse(new MyEntity()));
    model.put("entityName", "myEntity");

    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Field field : MyEntity.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
      if (!field.getName().equals("id"))
        fields.add(field.getName());
    }

    model.put("fields", fields);

    return "edit-page";
  }
}
```

In details: 
I have a simple entity "user"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_tbl")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private int age;

  public User() {
  }

  public User(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

To add or edit this user entity I created the following form (omitting the controller code and some markup around the form):

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/edit-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" id="id"/>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Alter</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{age}" id="age" placeholder="age" class="form-control">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">save</button>
    </form>
```

If I am going to create another entity anotherUser I am going to copy paste all this and may be change some names or fields or what so ever, but it's totally similar to each other...

Is there a way to do this once and reuse for all my other entities I will define?

Comment: It can be done but it is hard to do that. Writing generic code for all object types is cumbersome because firstly when you iterate over all fields of the bean to display an input element you would want to show different types of input elements (sometimes textbox, sometimes checkbox, sometimes combobox and etc.) which is hard if you dont maintain an input type with the field.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, thanks for your reply. Yes you're right and I thought about that. I might achieve that with (custom) annotations. Yet, I don't want to go that far. For now I'm just asking for existing concepts or existing strategies :)